# canvg toDataURL not returning full image with large chart

Tags: canvg

I have chart with `4000 x 10000(+)`. 
While converting the image it is returning 4000 x 8000 image which is not full image.

```
Code : var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'); 
canvg(canvas, this.canvas.toSVG());  // this : rapheal object
var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
```

Comment: I note you have opened this issue on GitHub https://github.com/gabelerner/canvg/issues/408 but this looks to be a previously known issue: https://github.com/gabelerner/canvg/issues/215

Comment: So no solution for now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The max resolution supports 8192 px. So solve this problem by compress the image to max height of 8192 px if the height is more than that using scaleHeight property.

```
var maxChartHeight = 8192;
canvgOpt.scaleHeight = Math.min( canvas.height, maxChartHeight );
canvg( chartCanvas, canvas.toSVG(), canvgOpt );
```